# type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed when i send '/'

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticSearch with RestHighLevelClient and Java. When I put query:
QueryBuilder qb = new QueryStringQueryBuilder("*" + valueSearch.toLowerCase() + "*"). Where valueSearch contain "/" -> example REC2/. The searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT) return me Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed].
However, when I send Rec2/2/3 or Rec// everything its ok.

Version elastic: 7.3.0

Comment: Can you share the ES server logs, the detailed error must be there.

Comment: Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]

Comment: and now I found: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"Failed to parse query [*list/*]","index_uuid":"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query_string` query has some [reserved characters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters) that you're now allowed to use in queries (such as `/`), except if properly escaped.

So you should escape all reserved characters that are present in `valueSearch.toLowerCase()`